# /api/auth/ error from NextAuth.js deployed in Vercel

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

use vercel environment variables to put NEXTAUTH_URL, NEXTAUTH_SECRET, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, but it didn't work. I also put them in the .env but it still doesn't work. This works perfectly on my local machine but the url that gives me vercel when deploying no longer works.
Any solution devs?

This is my route.js file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            profile(profile) {

                return {
                    id: profile?.sub,
                    username: profile?.email,
                }
            }
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "JuNRod"},
                password: {label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "*********"}
            },

            async authorize(credentials) {
                return {
                    username: credentials?.username,
                    password: credentials?.password
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({token,user}) {

    ¿Any solution Devs??        if (user) {
                token.username = user?.username
                token.password = user?.password
            }

            return token
        },
        async session({token}) {
            return token
        }
    },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export {
    handler as GET,
    handler as POST,
}
```

this is my directory:

[image: img1]

this is credentials in google

[image: img2]

[![img3][3]][3]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while deploying my Next.js application to vercel. Have you tried removing the double quotes`" "` around your vercel environment variables?

Go to your app `settings -> Environment Variables` and edit your `GOOGLE_AUTH` credentials

Comment: If dev, I tried putting those variables in the vercel environment variables and in my .env without " ", and nothing